# How to calculate a simple function for different groups of the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe (df)

```
   Index   A   B 
    0      1   1
    1      2   2
    2      3   3
```

and generated 20 resample data from this original data set all combined in one big data frame.

For instance:

```
         Resample Nr.       Index   A   B 
               1             0      1   1
               1              0      1   1
               1              2      3   3 
              20             2      3   3
              20               1      2   2
              20               1      2   2
```

I want to apply a function on each group and generate a New column. For instance:

```
 New Column = sum(df['A'] * df['B']) / sum(df['A'] ** 2)) --> Only Data set 1
 New Column = sum(df['A'] * df['B']) / sum(df['A'] ** 2)) --> Only Data set..
 New Column = sum(df['A'] * df['B']) / sum(df['A'] ** 2)) --> Only Data set 20
```

my goal is to calculate this function for the different resampled data chunks of the dataframe. So for 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 20.

How is this possible for each data group/chunk?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not the other way around? `np.array_split((df.A+df.B)/df.A, X)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use df.apply() function

```
def sum_func(df): # defined funtion
    return (df['A']+ df['B']/df['A'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[1,2,3]} )   # dataframe

# new column
df['C'] = df.apply(sum_func, axis=1)    # function applied on dataframe


#Output
    A   B   C
0   1   1   2.0
1   2   2   3.0
2   3   3   4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.assign( c = lambda x: x.A + x.B/x.A, axis=1)['c'].groupby('Resample Nr.').sum()
```

Please refer to [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for more details.

Comment: @LinhTran You may need to give an example of your group idea. The function mentioned in your question makes no difference whether or not you group the data.

Comment: I also edit the original post to clarify my problem. Thanks

Comment: @LinhTran  I assume the Resample Nhr. is an index and in that case you can use`groupby(level=0)`.

Comment: @LinhTran I have added a reference to `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` for your reference and edited the answer accordingly.